# What is JP used for in Grand Theft Auto Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

After completing a job online with some friends I received: 15 JP, 2590 RP (Experience) and ~$3500.

I am assuming JP stands for Job Points? .... What are they used for?

Comment: My friend and I were thinking they might be needed to obtain means for online heists when those are released, but that's just our speculation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JP are indeed job points. As of now - they are used to determine tiebreakers. 
They are shown in the list of players and reset to 0 after every session.

Answer (score 5):

There is not much information on JP.
Some call it **Job Points**, others **Judge Points**.
The only thing I could muster was a theory.

Since **you lose JP every time you die or lose a game mode**, can be considered a score of consecutive victories to determine your ranking in the Playlist, and other players can judge you if you are a good choice for the amount of JP.